# transfer learning on custom CNN using keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I have built a custom CNN with this structure:

```
arCNN.summary()

conv2d_141 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 16, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_150 (Bat (None, 16, 16, 256)       1024      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_142 (Conv2D)          (None, 14, 14, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_151 (Bat (None, 14, 14, 256)       1024      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_143 (Conv2D)          (None, 12, 12, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_152 (Bat (None, 12, 12, 256)       1024      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_144 (Conv2D)          (None, 6, 6, 256)         1638656   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_37 (Dropout)         (None, 6, 6, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_145 (Conv2D)          (None, 6, 6, 512)         1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_153 (Bat (None, 6, 6, 512)         2048      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_146 (Conv2D)          (None, 6, 6, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_154 (Bat (None, 6, 6, 512)         2048      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_147 (Conv2D)          (None, 4, 4, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_155 (Bat (None, 4, 4, 512)         2048      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_148 (Conv2D)          (None, 2, 2, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_156 (Bat (None, 2, 2, 512)         2048      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_149 (Conv2D)          (None, 1, 1, 512)         6554112   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_38 (Dropout)         (None, 1, 1, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_9 (Flatten)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_36 (Dense)             (None, 512)               262656    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_157 (Bat (None, 512)               2048      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_37 (Dense)             (None, 512)               262656    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_158 (Bat (None, 512)               2048      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_38 (Dense)             (None, 512)               262656    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_159 (Bat (None, 512)               2048      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_39 (Dropout)         (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_39 (Dense)             (None, 20)                10260     
=================================================================
Total params: 19,344,660
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 19,344,660
_________________________________________________________________
```

I would like to exploit transfer learning by keeping the convolutional layers of this model and add a new head to train on new data.

How can I achieve that? (I have seen plenty of material online on retraining a standard CNN but I'm struggling to remove the head of the custom one I have which doesn't come with a parameter include_top=False)

Comment: `include_top=False` is specific to certain models that `keras` supports, I doubt you're gonna be able to directly produce a model that has that property. I'd suggest making a model by either 1) chopping off a layer of your model or by 2) using the weights of this model to load into another model with your new `top`.

Comment: @top how do I achieve (1) without having to retrain the model from scratch? how would I achieve (2)?

Comment: In the functional API, you can make use of `model.layers[0].input` and `model.layers[-2].output`. When transferring weights, you can do so manually with `model.layers[0].get_weights()` and `model.layers[0].set_weights()` (not sure bout set weights but definitely get)

Comment: I get it know, thanks @MZ

Comment: hey, do you know to how to apply this if I make custom model?